# Transfer Windows 10 Pro volume upgrade license

Tags: windows-10, licensing, volume-license

I have 2 computers, both came with Windows 10 Home licenses. For one of them, I've upgraded it to Pro using my employer's volume license.

Is it possible to downgrade the computer with the Pro license and do the upgrade in the other one with the same license? And if so, what would be the procedure?

Comment: Yes, Format the machine with Professional and install Home.  Then do Ann in-place upgrade of the other machine.  Windows cannot be in-placed downgraded from Professional to Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it possible to...upgrade...the other one with the same license?**

No. Volume upgrade licenses for the Windows OS merge the original license with the upgrade license, creating a single licence. It's a violation of the EULA to separate them once a system has been upgraded.

Your organization's Microsoft licensing administrator should have access to the full text of the EULA governing your volume licenses and be able to confirm this.

*Note that I've not addressed whether it's* technically *possible to do this given doing so would violate the EULA and put your employer at risk of failing a Microsoft license audit.*